# Forecasting model

Tags: forecasting, model

My task is 'unemployment forecasting'. I have data with monthly ammount of unemployed. 
First as I do was : simple exp smoothing, holt's method, Holt-Winters method, ARMA model. All this models take only 1 series and build prediction based only on historical data.

Now I need to forecast unemployment using such data as unemployment benefits, gross domestic product, Consumer price index, etc.

example of dataset: 
[image]

My scientific adviser suggest to use neural network. But I dont think that it will do good forecasts (because of small amount of features).

What methods (which based not only on 1 column, but on all predictors) can I use for forecasting?

Answer (score 1):

I'd review the chapter here: https://www.otexts.org/fpp/9/1

Neural networks require extreme amounts of data and many more features than you have for them to typically outperform other time series methods.